# Run C++ code on web server and call it from an application

Tags: c++, web-services, web-applications

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to web development and server management, as I've always coded desktop applications.

I want to make a desktop application which does this

- Send data to a web server (http://... address)
- The web server receives the data and does calculations via a C++ application stored on the web server itself
- The web server returns the computed value to the desktop application

Is this possible? Where do I get started?

My web host is http://www.namecheap.com/

Comment: yes. http://www.treefrogframework.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you want to create a Common Gateway Interface (CGI). If you are a newbie take a look at [CGI programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

Answer (score 1):

With Boost Asio you can program your own server and client in C++, and process what you want in C++.

Look at the tutorials, there are several examples of [HttpServer and HttpClient](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).